How to get rid of "x" clear button in WPF textbox when using Fluent theme
When I upgraded my WPF application to .NET 9 and I used Fluent theme, a clear button "x" was added to the multi line textboxes like this:
 <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" />


Look at the right side of the picture. There is a "x" button there.
How can I hide this button?

To hide the clear "x" button in a multi-line TextBox under the Fluent theme in .NET 9, you can use the TextBox.ClearButtonEnabled property, which is set to True by default in Fluent. Set it to False in your XAML like this:
<TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" ClearButtonEnabled="False"/>

I have updated code use this pls try this
    using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Create a new TextBox programmatically
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox
            {
                AcceptsReturn = true,
                Width = 300,
                Height = 100
            };

            // Create a custom Style for the TextBox to remove the clear button
            Style textBoxStyle = new Style(typeof(TextBox));

            // Create a new setter for the ClearButtonStyle and set it to Collapsed
            textBoxStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBox.ClearButtonStyleProperty, null));

            // Apply the custom style to the TextBox
            textBox.Style = textBoxStyle;

            // Add the TextBox to the Window (or a container like Grid)
            this.Content = textBox;
        }
    }
}


I can't find it: The member "ClearButtonEnabled" is not recognized or is not accessible.

pls share ss of code where you are trying to implement

@MahdiAtaollahi I have updated code  pls check this too
